# How to get the power series expansion of this

Tags: power-series

How to get the power series expansion of 1/(1-z^2-z) at z=0? I have tried many ways but failed to find the law of the coefficients.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have tried to get the derivative but after some times it’s kind of unrealistic for me to keep dong so.

Comment: This was asked just some minutes ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528782/the-coefficients-of-the-power-series-frac11-z-z2-centered-at-0-are-the

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The coefficients of the power series $\frac{1}{1-z-z^2}$ centered at $0$ are the numbers in the Fibonacci sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528782/the-coefficients-of-the-power-series-frac11-z-z2-centered-at-0-are-the)